# Microsoft Cognitive Services: Bing Speech Recognition XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, bing

I am trying to develop a humble AI to help the daily routines of my family.
Voice recognition is a must, and commands can not be limited to a command library.

- so command library mode is out of the table
- I tried dictation mode, which already has a terrible recognition with headset, wont be able to understand anything with a room mic.
- So I am trying to use Microsoft Cognitive Services: Bing Speech Recognition:
  I downloaded the documents and the example, I see everything is in XAML form. I don't understand why.
  I am asking some guidance from those who are experienced in this, is it possible to make it in console app or windows form? (I am using .Net 4.6).
  If not do you have any suggestion for me to solve my problem?
  Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Technically you can use anything that speaks HTTP, but you probably want to [use the .Net API Cient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition-x86/) which can be referenced in any type of .Net application you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NuGets to achieve the same. Find sample over here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows

Further details about BingSpeechSDK -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Speech/GetStarted/GetStartedCSharpDesktop

You can use the same for Console App also just need to define the input segment from MicIn.